# Comparison of memory consumption between standard simulation of Brownian motion and Brownian bridge construction

Tags: matlab

I want to plot the memory used on the Y-axis and time steps on the X-axis of the standard Brownian motion and the Brownian bridge construction on MATLAB. I cannot seem to find anything online in regards to this so I am a bit lost. Here is what my MATLAB code is for just the Brownian motion.

```
mu = .0125;
sigma = .08;
N = 200;
displacement = normrnd(mu,sigma,N,N);
x = cumsum(displacement);
plot(x);
ylabel('position');
xlabel('time step');
```

This is what I want the plot to sort of look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you mean by "memory used". If you mean the memory used by all of the variables, then you could clear your workspace and then just add up all of the sizes of the variables...

```
clear;
a = whos;
s = 0
for i = 1:numel(a)
   s = s + a(i).bytes
end
disp([ int2str(s), ' bytes used' ])
```